# Align object according to axis

Tags: objects, 3d-view, coordinates

how I can cordinate/align a object according a axis(Z,X,Y)?

This is the top view, and as you can see, its not correct.
[image]
This is the front view, as you can see its slightly not according to the axis.
[image]

Comment: I m not sure what exactly you meant by aligning.But try Ctrl+Shift and rotating the middle mouse button and see if that's what you meant.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground/56886#56886

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use align rotation of the snapping tool. But you have to align an object with straight axes onto your mesh and then rotate it back.
[image: Align trick]

Comment: There are a number of ways this can be done - but this way is pretty smart :)

Comment: This seems to answer the question I myself have, but I can't manage to understand it. Do you "use align rotation" before or after aligning the cube with the thing ? What is happening to the initial object's set of axis that makes it so you can enter 0 in Z and it unrotates it, but you couldn't unrotate it that way before aligning the cube ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Align rotation is active when snapping. Then I join the old mesh to the cube so that its coordinate system is overwritten, you could also use a parent-child dependency. Finally I set the object rotation to 0 by hand.

Comment: Thanks : "joining the old mesh to the cube to overwrite the old coordinate system" is the key point I missed.