# Rotate a mesh selecting 3 points which will be the floor

Tags: coordinates

In Zephyr, I've seen that there is a functionality to rotate the mesh selecting 3 points which will be the floor.
Do we have such functionality in Blender? This is quicker that playing with the gizmo

Video of someone using that functionality on Zephyr: https://youtu.be/N9qnTkLgPEc?t=351 the youtuber says "level-up"

Zephyr icon:
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground/56886#56886

Comment: I don't know if there's a direct way to do it, but you can either snap to a face or align the origin orientation to a face

Comment: It seems that there is a plugin Loopanar > Put on : https://sourceforge.net/p/blendamajigs/wiki/Loopanar/ , but I cannot make it works :( (found on the @DuarteFarrajotaRamos answer page)