How to re-orientate a mesh with messed up world co-ordinates
I am very new to Blender so apologies is if this obvious.
I have downloaded a mesh from the Internet and one part of it is an eye for a cartoon character. The short of this is that I want to 3d print it but whenever I "slice" it in my 3d printing software, it is not coming out clean because the object is skewed as you will see in the image.
I want to re-orientate it correctly and save it as a new mesh so that it is orientated correctly with the correct planes. Wondering how I might do that. I have tried using snap to a plane and it still orientates it wrong. You can see from the image that it clearly was made originally on the angle I want to put it on, but for some reason was saved as an STL being on a slant.
I know I can rotate it manually, but this is a pain and it still does not print correctly sometimes. How might I go about doing this?
The mesh is in two parts, the outer eye and the pupil. Once I re-orientate the outer eye correcly, I'd also like to move the pupil to be exactly in the middle and orientated correctly as well.
Even this didn't work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7W46Cxvn0I&t=10s
Thanks,


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground/56886#56886

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos that doesn't work, I already tried it

In Edit mode select an edge loop you want the origin to be aligned with, in the Transform Orientations panel click on the "+" and keep the new orientation selected:

In Object mode activate the Only Affect Origins option:

Go into Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation so that the origin align with the custom orientation:

Deactivate the Affect Only Origins option and press AltR to reset the rotation, then rotate it along the desired axis and apply the rotation with CtrlA:


One way of doing it would be to, in Object mode, select the orgin manipulation on the top Right drop menu. This makes it so you are manipulating the origin and not the object mesh.
Then activate Snapping to Faces or Vertices with 'Align Rotation to target' enabled.
Then press G to move the origin and snap it to a vertice or face that is aligned with the orientation you want. For an object like that there's probably a vertex right in the middle of the bottom part that has the correct normal.

The snapping won't alight the Y and X normals of the object perfectly but if you just want it to be oriented upwards correctly then it's probably the fastest way.
Another solution is to just rotate the object manually. It will work with a regularly shaped obj like this, that has flat loops to use as reference
Just get a really close up view of the red X part in isometric view and put the cursor there. Then use the cursor as the pivot and rotate it until the green line aligns with the grid in the background. The closer you get to the ideal rotation the closed you can zoom in on the other side, blue circle, to make sure that it aligns with the grid there as well.
The object seems to only be rotated in the Y axis so this would also be pretty quick to do in this case. And past a certain point it doesn't really matter if the alignment is 100% or not for 3d printing

